# React-Bootstrap table with firebase realtime database creates new table for each entry

Tags: reactjs, firebase, forms, firebase-realtime-database, react-bootstrap

I'm a little stuck here.
Yesterday I finished coding this app to display entries from a form.
It worked fine and showed each entry as a separate row. Now I started the app this morning and suddenly each new entry is rendered as a new table?

I tried to keep the code as short as possible to avoid any confusion, but I just don't know how to get my beloved table back. I must've accidentally missed a line of code somewhere, but I've been looking at this for hours, and I can't figure it out.

Help would be much appreciated.

```
import { db } from "./firebase";
import { ref, onValue } from "firebase/database";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Table } from "react-bootstrap";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";

function App() {
    const [entires, setentires] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        onValue(ref(db), (snapshot) => {
            setentires([]);
            const data = snapshot.val();
            if (data !== null) {
                Object.values(data).map((date) =>
                    setentires((oldArray) => [...oldArray, date])
                );
            }
        });
    }, []);

    return (
        <div className="App">
            {entires.map((entry) => (
                <>
                    <Table responsive striped bordered hover size="sm">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th className="tableHeading">Date</th>
                                <th className="tableHeading">FirstName</th>
                                <th className="tableHeading">LastName</th>
                                <th className="tableHeading">Email</th>
                                <th className="tableHeading">Mobile</th>
                                <th className="tableHeading">Signature</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr key={entry}>
                                <td>{entry.date}</td>
                                <td>{entry.firstName}</td>
                                <td>{entry.lastName}</td>
                                <td>{entry.email}</td>
                                <td>{entry.phone}</td>
                                <td>
                                    <img
                                        alt="Signature"
                                        className="sigImage"
                                        src={entry.Signature}
                                    ></img>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </Table>
                </>
            ))}
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

`entries.map()` is returning a whole table for each entry in the array since you have the whole table JSX inside the map function.

What you could do is to have a variable what will iterate over your entries and only return individual table records, and just include those records in the return statement of the component.

Answer (score 0):

Every time something changes in the database, you get a snapshot with the entire data at `ref` and not just the changes. So you should replace the entire `entires` [sic] with the value from the snapshot.

In code that'd be something like:

```
onValue(ref(db), (snapshot) => {
    const data = snapshot.val();
    if (data !== null) {
        setentires(Object.values(data));
    }
});
```

Comment: This definitely is a better way of doing it, but it unfortunately didn't resolve my issue. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

**I ended up using a different form package (Material-Table) and managed to make it work.**

---

I also found a way to render images within the form, so that's a big bonus.

As you can see I ended up taking Frank van Puffelen's answer to simplify my data query.

Thanks for all the kind help!

```
import "../App.css";
import { db } from "../firebase";
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { ref, onValue } from "firebase/database";
import MaterialTable, { MTableToolbar } from "@material-table/core";
import { ExportCsv, ExportPdf } from "@material-table/exporters";

const DataTable = () => {
    const [Entries, setEntries] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        onValue(ref(db), (snapshot) => {
            const data = snapshot.val();
            if (data !== null) {
                setEntries(Object.values(data));
            }
        });
    }, []);

    const data = Entries;
    const columns = [
        {
            field: "date",
            title: "Date",
            width: "200px",
        },
        { field: "firstName", title: "First Name", width: "200px" },
        { field: "lastName", title: "Last Name", width: "200px" },
        { field: "email", title: "E-Mail", width: "300px" },
        {
            field: "Signature",
            title: "Signature",
            width: "150px",
            filtering: false,
            render: (rowData) => (
                <img alt="Signature" src={rowData.Signature} style={{ width: 100 }} />
            ),
        },
    ];

    return (
        <div className="App">
            <MaterialTable
                data={data}
                columns={columns}
                options={{
                    rowStyle: {
                        backgroundColor: "White",
                    },
                    headerStyle: {
                        backgroundColor: "lightgray",
                        color: "black",
                    },
                    showTitle: false,
                    search: false,
                    filtering: true,
                    exportMenu: [
                        {
                            label: "Export PDF",
                            exportFunc: (cols, datas) =>
                                ExportPdf(cols, datas, "myPdfFileName"),
                        },
                        {
                            label: "Export CSV",
                            exportFunc: (cols, datas) =>
                                ExportCsv(cols, datas, "myCsvFileName"),
                        },
                    ],
                }}
                components={{
                    Toolbar: (props) => (
                        <>
                            <div className="download">
                                <MTableToolbar {...props} />
                            </div>
                            <table className="toolBar">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr className="row">
                                        <th className="entryNum">
                                            Number of Entries : {props.data.length}
                                        </th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                            </table>
                        </>
                    ),
                }}
            />
        </div>
    );
};

export default DataTable;
```